# How to force to click X(close, back button) in Displaymode (3) of VrVideoView?

Tags: google-vr, vrvideoview

I am making a VR Android application using VrVideoView. I want to force "close(X, back button)" to be clicked after the video is played. That is, I want to return to MainActivity after the video finishes. Below is the codes I've tried. However, I did not go back to MainActivity after the video was finished. If you know how, please let me know.

1.

```
videoWidgetView.pauseVideo();
videoWidgetView.seekTo(0);
videoWidgetView.shutdown();
```

2.

```
videoWidgetView.pauseVideo();
videoWidgetView.seekTo(0);
finishActivity(0);
```

3.

```
videoWidgetView.pauseVideo();
videoWidgetView.seekTo(0);
findViewById(R.id.ui_back_button).performClick();
```

4.

```
videoWidgetView.pauseVideo();
videoWidgetView.seekTo(0);
Field f;

try {

     f =videoWidgetView.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("vrUiLayer");
     f.setAccessible(true);
     UiLayer vrLayer = (UiLayer) f.get(videoWidgetView);

     vrLayer.getView().findViewById(R.id.ui_back_button).performClick();

} 
catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: videoWidgetView.setDisplayMode(1);

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override `OnDestroy` method and add these lines into it:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    videoWidgetView.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Then call `onDestroy()` method in `onCompletion` method:

```
    @Override
    public void onCompletion() {
        videoWidgetView.seekTo(0);
        videoWidgetView.pauseVideo();
        onDestroy();
    }
```

Hope it works :)